# Select para juntar duas tabelas Pai e Filho uma abaixo da outra

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como fazer para obter o resultado conforme a imagem, tenho uma coluna com `id` que vincula os registros pai e filho, eu sei que o `join` junta as tabelas lado a lado, porém, precisava juntar abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o operador UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT chave, Data_Venda, Qtde_Produto, Valor_Produto FROM Tabela_Pai
    UNION
    SELECT chave, Data_Venda, Qtde_Produto, Valor_Produto FROM Tabela_Filho
) temp
ORDER BY chave;
```